# delegate assigning in objective c++

Tags: ios, objective-c++

I want to assign **delegate** of `AsyncSockket` in my project.
In objective c, we can assign delegate as follow:

```
AsynSocket *socket = [[AsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
```

How to do similar thing in objective-c++ as self assigning can't be done in it.

Comment: Perhaps create a constructor that you pass `this`? `SomeClass obj(this);`

Comment: i tried passing this but delegate methods are not been assigned to it

Comment: Why not? objective c++ is simply objective c with c++ constructs. There should be no difference when assigning delegates. What is your error?

Comment: I think you need to post some code. What specifically is the code that is failing?

Comment: for objective c++ part of code refer link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/speakhere/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007802-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Comment: delegate of asyncSocket i have to assign in AQRecorder and AsyncSocket is in objective c